# How can I mock a Class in Laravel 8.0?

Tags: mocking, automated-tests, laravel-8, grecaptcha

I'm trying to test a form that has gRecaptcha:

I added a mock following the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#mocking-objects) :

```
$this->mock(GoogleRecaptcha::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
     $mock->shouldReceive('isValid')->once()->andReturn(true);
});
```

After that it runs the post request, but as it seems to actually be running the mocked class from the controller, it is throwing an error. I thought that the mock shouldn't run it. Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the mock.

In the controller, after the validation, it runs this code:

```
if (!(new GoogleRecaptcha)->isValid()) {
    abort(403, 'It seems that you are a robot');
}
```

The GoogleRecaptcha is just a class in the App\Support folder, with only one method: "isValid".

Thanks anyway. Hernán.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mock a class using laravel service container you must use dependency injection or service location. In this case, the test failed because the GoogleRecaptch class was instantiated using the reserved word **new**.

Change it to:

```
app(GoogleRecaptch::class)->isValid()
```

The service container will resolve it.